# how to change the edit pop css property of Jtable in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jqgrid, jquery-jtable

I have added below jtable references in the project but my edit pop and delete pop behaves very weirdly. I am searching and going through many tutorials on how to fix things but since I am very new to Jtable I am facing difficulties in fixing the edit pop design of Jtabel. Can any one please help me how can i make the edit pop look and feel?

My view :

```
![<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    @{
        @model abcFinal.Models.AdminCatgMgmt
        ViewBag.Title = "Process Manager :: Admin Category Manager";
    }
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Process Manager :: Admin Category Manager</title>
    <link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Content/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Scripts/jtable/themes/lightcolor/blue/jtable.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jtable/jquery.jtable.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Include one of jTable styles. -->
<link href="/jtable/themes/metro/blue/jtable.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<!-- Include jTable script file. -->
<script src="/jtable/jquery.jtable.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    @*<script src="~/scripts/adminorders/adminorders.js"></script>*@
    @*<script src="~/Scripts/jtable/localization/jquery.jtable.tr.js"></script>*@
    @*<script src="~/Content/AdminCategories/masinCategory.js"></script>*@

</head>
<body>

    <br />
    <h1>Process Manager :: Admin Category Manager</h1>
    <br />
    <div id="tabs" class =".mytab">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Main Category</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Sub Category</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">Country</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-4">State</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-5">City</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-6">Shipping</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-7">Extra Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-8">S-Category</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
            <div id="mainCategoryTableContainer" style ="width:770px;margin-left:70px;margin-top:30px">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2">
            <div id="subCategoryTableContainer" style ="width:770px;margin-left:70px;margin-top:30px">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-3">
            <div id="countryTableContainer" style ="width:770px;margin-left:70px;margin-top:30px">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-4">
            <div id="stateTableContainer" style ="width:800px;margin-left:70px;margin-top:30px">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-5">
            <div id="cityTableContainer" style ="width:800px;margin-left:70px;margin-top:30px">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-6">

        </div>
        <div id="tabs-7">

        </div>
        <div id="tabs-8">

        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            $("#tabs").tabs(
            {
                collapsible: true

            });

            //$(".my_tab").bind("click", handle_tab_click)

            $('#mainCategoryTableContainer').jtable({
                title: 'Main Category list',
                paging: true,
                pageSize: 10,
                sorting: true,
                defaultSorting: 'subcatname ASC',
                actions: {
                    listAction: '@Url.Action("getMainCategory")',
                    deleteAction: '@Url.Action("DeleteMainCategory")',
                    updateAction: '@Url.Action("EditMainCategory")',
                    createAction: '@Url.Action("AddMainCategory")'

                },
                fields: {
                    catid: {
                        title: 'Main Category Id',
                        width: '10%',
                        create: false,
                        edit: false,
                        key: true,
                        list: true
                    },
                    catname: {
                        title: 'Category Name',
                        width: '20%',
                        //edit: false,
                        //key: true,

                    },
                    noofsubcat: {
                        title: 'No. of Sub Category',
                        width: '10%',
                        create: false,
                        edit: false,
                    },
                    catdate: {
                        title: 'Sub Category Date',
                        width: '20%',
                        edit: false,
                        create: false,
                    }
                }
            });
            $('#mainCategoryTableContainer').jtable('load');
 });
    </script>
</body>
</html>][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you define "behaves very weirdly" ?

Just came across this question looking for something else, and at a quick glance the first thing I would do is include only one instance of jtable, not both:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jtable/jquery.jtable.js"></script>
```

...
and 
...

```
<!-- Include jTable script file. -->
<script src="/jtable/jquery.jtable.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You only need one and including 2 files albeit a minified version you'll create the possibility of double instantiation.